# Apache 500 error after installing APC extension

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I recently installed APC extensions for my default PHP installation. To facilitate the loading of this new extension I created a new php.ini in /private/etc/

So now this location contains both the new php.ini and the default, php.ini.default. The new php.ini is just a copy of the default one but with the added extension being loading in the dynamic extensions section.

When I attempt to access any page in my local/host/~username virtual directory I receive a server 500 error.

I viewed the logs located in /var/log/apache2/ but I don't see any log of a server 500 error.

I suspect that this error might be related to my having both the default and the new php.ini in the same directory.

Has anyone had this problem? Should I remove / rename the default configuration file?

This is the line that I added to the Dynamic Extensions section of php.ini

vim extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so

Comment: What did you do to make Apache use the right `php.ini` file? Do you have xcache installed? Please post your Apache configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run `ls /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so`. Is the extension binary there? If not, make sure it's properly installed.
2. The added line should probably be just `extension=apc.so`.
3. If it still doesn't work, make sure `extension_dir=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626` is in your php.ini.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I changed the my extension inclusion line to just be extension=apc.so I found a commented out line that said extension_dir = "./" I uncommented this line and changed the path to match the path to the folder containing my extension. No beans. I commented out the extension=apc.so line though and it works. So it it definitely the extension that is blowing me up.

Comment: 1) Wrong build (built for different PHP version, thread-safe/non-thread-safe, x32 / x64 bit) ? 2) Wrong APC configuration (how did you configured it)?

Comment: @LazyOne excuse my ignorance. I am new to PHP configuration. I compiled the extension and then just added the extension to the dynamic extension section of my php.ini. I was using some instructions I found online. Is there more configuration that needs to be done to the extension outside of just adding the extension to the php.ini?

Comment: @Nick Have a look here, maybe some default setting breaks everything: http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php